# Graphene Django File field get absolute path

Tags: django, graphene-django

I have an image field in my Django model and I am trying to get absolute path of the image field output from Graphene so as to connect to my client.

```
class ProfileType(DjangoObjectType): 
     class Meta: model = Profile

     def resolve_avatar(self, info, **kwargs):

    print(info.context.build_absolute_uri(self.avatar))
```

I do not get an absolute file field path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got an answer to this and I want to make sure I post it someone else does not make the same mistake.

Here is what the code should look like

```
class ProfileType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:

        model = Profile

    avatar          = graphene.String()
    cover_photo     = graphene.String()


    def resolve_avatar(self, info):

        return info.context.build_absolute_uri(self.avatar.url)

    def resolve_cover_photo(self, info):

        return info.context.build_absolute_uri(self.cover_photo.url)
```

Answer (score 2):

If Profile.avatar is ImageField you should use self.avatar.url instead of self.avatar:

```
info.context.build_absolute_uri(self.avatar.url)
```